# How can i open sublime text editor with termial on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: command-line, sublime-text

I want open sublime text editor via terminal, already i can it open via `subl` command, but problem is when i open editor then terminal loading like as below

```
(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28265 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28323 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28383 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28439 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28502 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28564 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

I want both working sublime text and with terminal, how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried redirecting the standard and error output to /dev/null ?

```
subl > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: When back to terminal then show me error, i want both working after open sublime...then also i want terminal command line work

Comment: Just gived a try to sublime and redirecting outputs like suggested seems to do the trick